# How to describe a "footedly" person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing someone can “sit still” and doing something persistently, who can stick up to something for years. How to describe this characteristic? Such as steadfast, footed... I just cannot get a satisfied one.

And how to describe the opposite, antonym of it? One that always switches his/her mind and cannot stick up to one thing.

Thanks. Word or phrase will help.

Comment: To stick to one thing. I don't believe sure-footed is the term you are looking for. It is the only  one I know with "footed". Perhaps you might mean: **well-grounded in a field or subject**, Knowing it well.

Comment: Someone who can stick to the same thing for a long time might be "focused", while someone who cannot could be "flighty".

Comment: Thanks, @Lambie, but I am not saying s/he is good or having a solid background in a field, I just want to say his/her attitude. "sure-footed" is a good term for my purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @Hellion, hm, these two words are good. What do you think of the word "frivolous", similar to "flighty"?

Comment: Why did someone downvote my question, it feels hurt.

Comment: @YangxinZhang I don't think "frivolous" fits well; it means the person or activity is not serious or meaningful, but it's entirely possible for someone to be completely focused on a frivolous goal.  (Like, for example, collecting every possible hat on Stack Exchange during Winter Bash.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the "footedly" or other words pertaining to foot are coming from.  However, there are a few words you could use that would depend on context.

For someone who's attentive of, e.g., a relationship with a person over a long time, I would suggest the words "devoted," "committed," "faithful" (the first two words carry a romantic connotation, whereas faithful can be to a romantic partner or a friend, or a business, etc.).

For someone who's deeply committed to their craft, or an art, etc., "committed" could still work, or you could go with "dedicated," or "absorbed" (especially if they're dedicated to the degree of preoccupation).  Saying someone is "married to" their craft or their art, or their idea, etc., would also similarly imply a negative sense of obsession (a workaholic is married to their job, for example).

"**Perseverant**" (as in, someone who perseveres) is uncommon, but could be used to describe someone who, over a period of time, sticks to a course of action or a plan, or an abstract purpose, especially through adversity or great difficulty.  Someone who lacks musical talent would persevere (or be perseverant) if they taught themselves how to play piano, for example.

"Constant" also describes someone who is dedicated to something, especially long-term.  However, this usage is uncommon, and seems to be used only in news (e.g. a "constant supporter" of something), or in the set phrase ("constant admirer").

As for an antonym...

"Flake" (slang, noun), "undedicated," "**desultory**" (lacking in consistency) could work.  Someone who is "dilettante" (can be an adjective, but much more commonly a noun) shows mere casual, passing interests in this or that (e.g. culture, sciences, arts).

Answer (score 0):

You might try [intent](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/intent_2).

For opposite [capricious](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/capricious)